# Citric Acid from Aspergillus Niger

Tags: organic-chemistry

Can anyone point me towards an experiment guideline of some sort regarding fermentation of citric acid from Aspergillus Niger? I haven't been able to find one by myself. I've found plenty of research papers, but none with any sort of guideline.

Comment: Not that this isn't Chemistry...but this is (probably) better off on the Biology.SE [ https://biology.stackexchange.com/ ]. You're asking for an experimental *guideline*, which is within the scope of the [organic-chemistry] tag...just letting you know there's another site for Biology-ish questions ;)